# C# Create Assembly and set Version - During runtime

Tags: c#, testing, version

I'm doing Unit-Tests and I want to test this:

```
public static string GetVersion(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```

The Question is in the Title.

Is this even possible?

Comment: you want to change the version of your own assembly or of the assembly passed to that method?

Comment: I want to create the Assembly and set the version programmaticaly. The I pass the Assembly to my Method, to test, if the Version is right.

Comment: Ok you have assembly A that has a Version and you have a assembly B that should check if A has a certain version? And assembly A should create its version programmatical?

Comment: Unit testing the framework itself looks rather pointless...

Answer (score 1):

I think through reflection you can change the response of the Property but its not written to the assembly it self.

```
PropertyInfo nameProperty = typeof (Version).GetProperty ("Version");
FieldInfo versionField = nameProperty.GetBackingField ();
versionField.SetValue (assemby.GetName().Version, <Version you want>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a [mock object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).  Create a fake type that "mocks" the Assembly type, and use that fake type for testing. Much easier than trying to get the universe to bend to your will just to test that your code handles obscure corner cases.

Scout around, there are multiple libraries to create mock types.  Here's one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx

Comment: That one is from 2004, so maybe not the best example... all string-based, no compiler support, not refactor-friendly. Moq, RhinoMocks, or TypeMock would probably be better starting points.

Comment: Like I said, scout around and find one that works well for you. The MSDN link is the first thing that popped up in a google search for "mock testing .net"  Lather. Rinse. Repeat.